# How to trace the recursion of a method from the first method call to the base case in java?

Tags: java, recursion

Consider the following code snippet.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
   int[] arrayOfInts = {5, 7, 5, 6, 4, 2, 3, 8, 4, 5, 2, 1, 8};
   System.out.println("The result is: " + rangeSum2(arrayOfInts, 4, 7)
}

public static int rangeSum2(int[] array, int start, int end) 
{
    if (start == end)
        return array[start];
    else if (start > end)
        return 0;
    else
        return array[start] + rangeSum2(array, start + 1, end - 1) + array[end];
}
```

How can I see what each method call outputs for the start and end variable and what does each method call return? 
The final result of the sum from index 4 to index 7 is 17. 
Also, when I pass the int of 4 and 7, does the method consider 4 and 7 or the 4th and 7th index values of the array?

From my understanding I trace each method call like this:
1st Method call 
start: 4
end: 7
return: 4 + rangeSum2(array, 5, 6) + 7
2nd method call 
start: 5 
end: 6
return 5 + rangeSum2(array, 6, 5) + 6
etc... 
I am just having trouble with knowing what values does the method use each recursion.

Comment: Why don't you simply trace it in a debugger?

Comment: "How can I see what each method call outputs for the start and end variable and what does each method call return" - the simple basic way is do print outs. A much more powerful yet easy enough is a [debugger](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDebugging/article.html)

Answer (score 0):

After the first call you're using the following recursion to the method:

`rangeSum2(array, start + 1, end - 1)`, meaning that:

**Call 1**:

```
start = 4, end = 7
```

**Call 2**:

```
start = 5, end = 6  because of rangeSum2(array, 4 + 1, 7 - 1)
```

**Call 3**:

```
start = 6, end = 5  because of rangeSum2(array, 5 + 1, 6 - 1)
```

In the end, you end up with:
4 + 2 + 3 + 8 + 0

Comment: Where does the zero come from?

Comment: @learningjava6
you set this condition:

`else if (start > end) return 0;`

Comment: While this may be correct, how does it answer "How can I see what each method call outputs for the start and end variable and what does each method call return" ?